# adding date to beginning of file name using script

Tags: files, scripting, date

I have multiple files that need to be renamed with a date added to the beginning of the file name that I am trying to script.

I'm using the `cp` command because I need to keep the original file

I need the file to be `YYYYMMDDfile.txt`

I have used every timestamp configuration (date '+%Y%m%d') but am having no luck. I have no problems adding timestamp to end of file name just the beginning.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are doing wrong but the following works:

```
for i in *; do cp "$i" $(date '+%Y%m%d')"$i"; done
```

(you should only run this once in a directory)